# GCC: check if compiling as library or executable

Tags: c++, gcc

I have some class implementation that is going to function as a Lib. 
However, I want to include a `main` function in that library with a simple driver testing my class. The function `main` can therefore be only compiled if I define my compilation target as an executable.

Can this be done via some macro or similar?

I would not like to create a new project nor Makefile, just a simple `#ifdef` wrapping the main function would be perfect for this job.

Comment: Compiling as executable or as library don't involve the same gcc commands. You definitively need a makefile.

Comment: Providing a main in a library is not a very good idea. Call your function, `test` or something like that.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Answer (score 2):

You can define a macro with the `-D` option of GCC. For instance, you can define a macro `_RELEASE` with option `-D_RELEASE` and wraps as the following:

```
#ifdef _RELEASE
// Release main
int main()
{
    // ...
}

#else
// Another main
int main()
{
    // ...
}

#endif
```

You can compile a main or another by adding `-D_RELEASE` to your compilation line:

```
gcc main.c -D_RELEASE [other flags] # compile with release main
gcc main.c [other flags] # compile with other main
```

### NOTE

This is an example for a `main` function, but of course it can be implemented for any function in a library.

Comment: But when compiling the library, you also need to set the good flags and/or run other programs after compilation. A makefile is definitively needed.

Comment: @mikedu95: a `Makefile` is *not required* to build a library; you could build it with a command like `gcc -Wall -O -fPIC *.c -shared -o libfoo.so` ; but indeed a `Makefile` is *convenient*

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch If your project is in C++ and if you have a lot of files, you'll have time to drink a coffee each time you compile without a Makefile...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sorry, "needed" is too severe, I agree. But if you want to sometimes build an exe, sometimes a static lib, or a dynamic lib, etc. You've better to use a makefile and *no preprocessor trick*, instead of using a preprocessor trick *plus* switching between all the commands to type. Let alone the suboptimized buliding process due to the absence of a makefile.

Comment: There are other builders than `make`, e.g. `omake`, `scons`; and GNU `make` itself can be built *without* `make` (even if it would be faster built with `make -j`)

Answer (score 0):

No, this can't be done by a macro. Wrong phase of compilation. Both C and C++ have 3 relevant steps: Per Translation Unit, the preprocessor and the compiler itself are run. Finally, the TU's are linked together by the linker.

While preprocessing or compiling an individual TU, you can't know what other TU's might contain, or what you will be linked into. In fact, it's quite possible that the makefile defines rules either way. E.g. file1.obj might go **both** into A.LIB and A.EXE.